ODE with additional parameter - Comparison of various limiting solutions
I am trying to solve the following ODE, where s is the independent variable, and k is a parameter
$$
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{s}^{2}}}T \left( s \right) 
 \right) {s}^{3}+ \left( -2\,k{s}^{3}-2\,{s}^{2} \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}s}}T \left( s \right) -16\,T \left( s \right)  \left( 1
/8\,k{s}^{2}+s/4 \right) =0
$$
When it is solved directly (MAPLE) we get
$$
T \left( s \right) ={\frac {{\it \_C1}}{s}}+{\frac {{\it \_C2}\,{
{\rm e}^{2\,ks}} \left( 2\,{k}^{4}{s}^{4}-4\,{k}^{3}{s}^{3}+6\,{k}^{2}
{s}^{2}-6\,ks+3 \right) }{s}}
$$
and if we take the k=0 limit of this solution, we get
$$
T \left( s \right) ={\frac {{\it \_C1}}{s}}+3\,{\frac {{\it \_C2}}{s}}
$$
So I decided to cross-check this against substituting k=0 into the original ODE, and then solving that, which gives
$$
T \left( s \right) ={\frac {{\it \_C1}}{s}}+{\it \_C2}\,{s}^{4}
$$
This is clearly different to the solution obtained from the first approach, yet both satisfy the ODE. So what has gone wrong? And how do we get the solution obtained from the first approach to contain that from the second approach as a subcase?
The other unusual behavior that I see is that if one was to take the large s limit of the solution from the first method, we get $ 2\,{\it \_C2}\,{{\rm e}^{2\,ks}}{k}^{4}{s}^{3}$, yet if we then substitute this into the large s limit of the ODE itself
$$
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{s}^{2}}}T \left( s \right) 
 \right) {s}^{2}-2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}s}}T \left( s
 \right)  \right) k{s}^{2}-2\,T \left( s \right) ks=0
$$
we find that it does not satisfy that ODE. Indeed, if you solve that ODE directly, the solution involves an 'Ei' integral. Again, how do we get the two approaches to be consistent?

Ok I have corrected it. But the solutions are still valid.

$$T(s)= \frac{c_2(k) e^{2 k s} \left(2 k^4 s^4-4 k^3 s^3+6 k^2 s^2-6 k s+3\right)}{s}+\frac{c_1(k)}{s}$$
Also valid solution.
